# Why is the hover tooltip over the tray clock in Windows XP unreliable?

Tags: windows, taskbar, notification-area, clock

Sometimes it appears behind the taskbar.  Sometimes it doesn't appear at all.

Is there a way to fix it, or maybe a nice, unobtrusive way to see today's date?

Comment: I find the hover tooltips to be a bit erratic across the entire taskbar, not just the tray clock

Answer (score 3):

**Taskbar - Tool Tips Hidden Behind the Task Bar:  FIX**

Go to Start/All Programs:  Hover over any program listed, right click and select Sort by Name.  Repeat once more.  All done!

*Source: [Kellys Korner](http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_t.htm)*

Comment: How does this even make sense? lol. I'm not doubting that it might work it just boggles the mind. How is arranging the programs in the start menu by name related to the Z-Index of a tooltip.

Comment: it's probably the funniest windows fix ever, because the solution seems totally and utterly unrelated to the problem ... but it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install any additional programs and want to be able to always see the date you can make a minor tweak. If you change the height of the taskbar to be taller, then it will show the date beneath the clock, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

on mine, when it times out and disappears, it won't come back right away like other icons do. If I click on the start button and then click on a blank spot on the task bar it comes back.